# third order ODE given 1 solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i've been given the following third order ODE and one solution to it:

$y''' + 7y'' + 16y' + 10y = 0$ with $ \lambda = -1$ as a solution

I'm not quite sure if my approach is correct but this is what I've done:

The characteristic equation for the third order ODE becomes:

$(\lambda + 1)(\lambda^2 + a \lambda + b)$

$ \lambda^3 + (a+1)\lambda^2 + (a+b)\lambda + b = 0$

Then i equated the $(a+1)$ and $(a+b)$ coefficients in the characteristic equation to the original ODE to get:

$(\lambda + 1)(\lambda^2 + 6\lambda + 10) = 0 $.
Then i solved the ODE as usual for a second order ODE from here. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Yes your approach is correct, and I showed it, and even posted a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}$
Your approach is correct, and one way that I check the solution for you is by solving the problem completely to show how that $\lambda$ is going to be play out. The first thing we are going to do is write the characteristic polynomial.

\begin{align}\la^3+7\la^2+16\la+10&=0\end{align}
Another tidbit to add is that we know that $\la=1$ is a solution. So one would have to use synthetic division.
\begin{array}{c|cccc}-1&1&7&16&10\\&&-1&-6&-10\\ &\hline1&6&10&0 \end{array} 
Therefore you new, and reformed characteristic polynomial is:
$$(\la+1)(\la^2+6\la+10)=0$$
Of course using the quadratic formula to break the quadratic into its factors, and its final reformed form:
$$(\la+1)(\la-3+i)(\la-3-i)=0$$
From here a solution can be put together by the following:
$$e^{-3x}(c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x))+c_3e^{x-}$$